# How to convert items in listView to files?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[image: files in listview1]

how i'm adding the files to the listview in constructor

```
listView1.View = View.List;
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\New folder (4)");
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(files[i]);
            }
```

for example the first file in the listview is d:\New folder (4)\myimage.jpg
when running the application i want to display the file in picturebox1

i tried this in the constructor

```
img1 = Image.FromFile(listView1.Items[0].ToString());
```

but getting error on that line

System.NotSupportedException: 'The given path's format is not supported.'

Comment: try this:     `img1 = Image.FromFile(listView1.Items[0].Text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to react to the `ItemSelectionChange` event of the `ListView` control.

Also use the `Text` property of the `ListViewItem` to access the text of the item.

```
private void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsSelected && e.Item != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Item.Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must read the `text of an item`. `Items[0] returns an object`. You must read the `Items[0].Text`: so edit this line:

```
//img1 = Image.FromFile(listView1.Items[0].ToString());
img1 = Image.FromFile(listView1.Items[0].Text);
```